# How Can I Rid off Redundant Values from a Column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

This is the sample output[image]

Let me explain what's going on:

The query returns all invoices # of every year along with the products
that is involved in the invoice.

As you see, we have two invoice in 2010...The invoices are 30463 and 30516.
The invoice 30463 has 4 products, its shipping price is 105.88. As you see
the shipping price is repeated on every product which causes troubles when
i calculate sum at reporting level. The 4 products of invoice # 30463 has
shipping price of 105.00 overall. I want every shipping price of every invoice
to be shown only once regardless how many products within an invoice. How can i achieve it?

HERE IS THE QUERY:

```
SELECT 
      DATEPART(year, CustomerInvDetail.sentDate) AS "Year", 
      CustomerInvoice.cuInvoiceID,  
      Product.productName, 
      CustomerQuoteProducts.unitPrice, 
      CustomerQuoteProducts.qty, 
      CustomerQuoteProducts.qty * CustomerQuoteProducts.unitPrice AS "Price",
      CustomerShipping.shippingPrice
FROM  CustomerInvoice INNER JOIN CustomerInvDetail 
      ON CustomerInvoice.cuInvoiceID = CustomerInvDetail.cuInvoiceID
      INNER JOIN CustomerQuote 
      ON CustomerQuote.customerQuoteID = CustomerInvoice.customerQuoteID
      INNER JOIN CustomerQuoteProducts 
      ON CustomerQuoteProducts.customerQuoteID = CustomerQuote.customerQuoteID
      INNER JOIN CustomerShipping 
      ON CustomerShipping.customerQuoteID = CustomerInvoice.customerQuoteID
      INNER JOIN Customer 
      ON Customer.customerID = CustomerQuote.customerID
      INNER JOIN Product 
      ON CustomerQuoteProducts.productID = Product.productID
WHERE (DATEPART(year, CustomerInvDetail.sentDate) BETWEEN 2001 AND 2022) AND (Customer.customerID = 500)
```

Comment: So, is your goal to have the 105.00 appear only once for the invoice with the remaining values in shippingPrice shown as zero?

Comment: You want to show all products but only once the price ?
Or you only want the price and id of each invoice ?

Comment: So for any given invoice number, you want the shipping price to only show up in one of the rows? Doesn't matter which row, as long as it only appears once?  All other shipping values for the invoice would be zero?

Comment: YES .... This is what i wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along these lines maybe?

```
case when row_number() over(partition by cuInvoiceId order by newid()) = 1 then shippingPrice end
```

**Update**

What it does is this:

1. It divides the data onto partitions depending on the `cuInvoiceId` value
2. Now, inside this partition we want to enumerate every row but there's nothing to anchor to so I used `newid()` which basically means enumerate those rows randomly.
3. And, finally, with `case ... = 1` I want the very first row to be the one that would display `shippingPrice` and all others -- `null`.

Comment: Awesome! Worked ... Can you please briefly explain what this line does...I see some new keywords such as partition...

Answer (score 0):

How about a case statement on the shipping price when it's the first item? I'm assuming you have a lineitem or some way to determining the first item on an invoice - then

case when lineno = 1 then CustomerShipping.shippingPrice else 0 end